# How to generate pdf documents from doxygen

Tags: c, pdf, doxygen

I m new to documentation and found that doxygen will save a hell of my time by it's cool tools.And i started experimenting with it using my c project which contain 3 source files.And right now im able to generate html/man/latex/doc files but i don't know how to generate pdf from the out put.

> So far i have installed doxygen and used command line interface to
>   generate Doxyfile. After that i have edited the doxyfile generated and
>
> set the command Doxygen doxyfile
>
> And output is generated is devoid of any pdf..but includes html refman and latex format.
>   I trust it is the latex format output coz the output is larger in size than .c source files.

What is the correct way of generating pdf using doxygen.It would be extremely helpful for me to find the correct way of usage.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

if it is a linux system, navigate to folder where latex and html folder is generated and do:

```
cd latex && make
```

Doxygen generates makefile and supporting tex files, once the make is run successfully it will generate document in the name of refman.pdf

Comment: @ChristianTernus I think the answer is correct as Vedas points out here the way how to build the pdf manual as a second step. The only clarification could be to mention that first steps as described by the OP have to de done and than the step in the answers from TRKemp and Vedas (depending on the OS).

Comment: @albert With the edits it's a lot better; removed my delete vote.

Answer (score 0):

In your latex directory is a batch file called, "make.bat". Execute it to produce your PDF, "refman.pdf".